# trying to copy PVC directory for backup solution

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using an NFS server as a Storage Class in my on-prom Kubernetes cluster. As part of testing, I manually copied some files into the Persistent Volume Claim (PVC) directory to see if I can consider it as a backup solution. However, when I try to access this data from inside the pod that has the PVC mounted, I encounter the following error:

> "ls: reading directory '.': Invalid argument.

Here's the series of steps I've taken:

- **PVC Creation**: I've created a Persistent Volume Claim using the NFS server as the Storage Class.
- **Mounting in Pod**: I've successfully mounted the PVC inside a pod, specifically at the path `/var/www/html`.
- **Copying Data**: From the NFS server, I've manually copied data into the directory associated with the PVC.
- **Access Attempt**: When I try to access the copied data from inside the pod (located at `/var/www/html`), I encounter the error message: ls: reading directory '.': Invalid argument.
- **Storage permission**: I've attempted to change the ownership of the copied files to match the user within the pod, but the issue persists.

Could anyone provide insights into why I might be facing this "Invalid argument" error when attempting to access the copied data from within the pod? Any suggestions for troubleshooting or resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if the pod can reach to NFS endpoint, or if the PVC is bound?

Comment: @NguyễnMinhHiếu, the PVC already was pounded on the pod and I can access it inside the pod , but when I copy files inside the PVC directory outside the pod (from the NFS) I got this error, if I remove the copied file I can access it again inside the pod.